# how to read paquet file having compressed with snappy to get rid of out-of-memory error?

Tags: python, deep-learning, out-of-memory, parquet

I have dataset in format of snappy.parquet (https://cernbox.cern.ch/files/public/show/hqz8zE7oxyPjvsL?items-per-page=100) of about 760 MB having 3 files. The dataset 4 feature x_jets, _ ,_  and y . I only require X_jet and y. I tried using pandas  below is the code.

```
df=pd.read_parquet('/kaggle/input/glucon/QCDToGGQQ_IMGjet_RH1all_jet0_run0_n36272.test.snappy.parquet',columns=['X_jets','y']) # this is just one file

df.memory_usage(deep=True)

Index         128
X_jets    4062464
y          290176
```

I try to change the datatype y.

```
df['y']=df['y'].astype('float16')
df.memory_usage(deep=True)

Index         128
X_jets    4062464
y           72544
dtype: int64

import fastparquet
print(fastparquet.ParquetFile('/kaggle/input/glucon/QCDToGGQQ_IMGjet_RH1all_jet0_run0_n36272.test.snappy.parquet').schema)

- schema: REQUIRED
| - X_jets: LIST, OPTIONAL
|   - list: REPEATED
|     - item: LIST, OPTIONAL
|       - list: REPEATED
|         - item: LIST, OPTIONAL
|           - list: REPEATED
|             - item: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
| - pt: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
| - m0: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
  - y: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
```

The datatype of `X_jets` is `object`. So is there any to reduce the memory of `X_jets`.

Another thing is i tried using dask reading the parquet file but at the end i need to convert it torch or tensor to train the model which again required lot of memory. Also pyspark also crashes.

Is there efficient way to read large parquet file and train it in the model. Or is there way read file using random sampling.

Comment: Is X_jets actually a deep nested, variable length field? You could do `print(fastparquet.ParquetFile(<path>).schema)`.

Comment: @mdurant yes i have also updated above. how Schema looks like ```- schema: REQUIRED
| - X_jets: LIST, OPTIONAL
|   - list: REPEATED
|     - item: LIST, OPTIONAL
|       - list: REPEATED
|         - item: LIST, OPTIONAL
|           - list: REPEATED
|             - item: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
| - pt: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
| - m0: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL
  - y: DOUBLE, OPTIONAL```

Comment: You can try the package Polars or modin

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try your data with awkward ( https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/ ), which is built to process non-tabular nested/variable length data like this.

import awkward as ak
arr = ak.from_parquet()

Awkward was originally written for high-energy physics particle data, which is what I suspect you are looking at. It provides numpy semantics and vectorised operation over your ragged data.

There is also a nascent package, awkward-pandas ( https://github.com/intake/awkward-pandas ) to provide the best of both, but it is not very mature.